# Profile photo and Bootstrap theme

Tags: bootstrap-4, laravel-livewire

I deploy the Laravel uploadfile for upload the profile photo to the user, and for that use livewire components inside Frest (Bootstrap theme). But I need in moment to save the image update the profile photo in navbar...and don't know how do that. Somebody can help me?

Comment: check this link. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#basic-upload

Comment: Oh yes, this part is accomplish. So I'm now dealing about a jQuery code to change in moment at save or change the photo in the component I can refresh the profile photo in the navbar, the img element on right top of navbar??? That part of my project isn't Livewire component and thinks that emits or dispatchBrowser events could help